# Shift an element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

1 - If the user press a key, my span is decaled on the right, and if he deletes the keys,  the span is decaled on the left ... The problem is that a user can still press the delete key, and there my code does not know how to handle it,

2 - I would also like the offset to be perfect according to the letter pressed ... ('a' doesn't have the same spacing as 'i' for example).

An idea ? Thanks !

### [My codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OWqveq)

```js
$('.field__input').keydown(function(e) {
  if ($('.field__input').val().length > 0) {
    if (e.which != 8) { //= delete key
      $('.search__results').css('display', 'block').css('left', '+=20');
    } else {
      $('.search__results').css('left', '-=20');
    }
  } else {
    $('.search__results').css('display', 'none');
  }
});
```

```css
.field--search {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  .field__input {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .search__results {
    color: red;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" placeholder="Search..." class="field__input">
<span class="search__results">26</span>
<button class="search__delete"></button>
```

Comment: interesting, but i wouldn't go with `keydown` and treat each key separately here, you could rather use `onchange` and calculate the offset based on total input length. This would cope with the delete problem. Concerning the letter size difference, it might change with font and browser, so i would use a hidden field in which you put the input content, and then retreive its width (considering it has the same font, size etc)

Comment: using onchange would only update the input box on blur

Comment: yes, you're right, i should sleep more these times :/ elegant solution btw

Answer (score 1):

1. in your first if statement. The else argument should set the left position back to it's original.
2. forget question 1 and approach it differently.

a. Create an empty span (display: inline-block and set the opacity to 0)

b. place it before your search__results.

on every keypress update the new span with the value of the input.  This will push the search__results span to the right to the size of the word. remember to not set a width on your new span. this way it will grow with your word.

Comment: A quick starter

[example codepen](http://codepen.io/branny/pen/bgZKqR)

If you style the fonts to be the same it should work out the spacing correctly